# How to make my old JFrame to JPanel, and how to make it actually work as it worked while I used JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Im really new to swing lib, like maybe 5 days ago I started using it... so I have so many problems... first, I made a Tic Tac Toe game on a JFrame, it would be cool to leave it like that, but then I came with the idea to make a small menu to acces multiple little games (just for fun/practice so far). So I actually succed, then it happens... I made all my games in JFrames so, to make a menu its also another JFrame, so I have so many windows... all the time!

I made some research and people usually makes Jpanels for this kind of stuff.. But I dont know how to transfer my games (Tic Tac Toe) to a JPanel and make it work exactly as it was... here is my code of the Tic Tac Toe in JFrame... the IDE is netbeans.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Gato extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {


Boton MAPA[][];


public static boolean turno=true;

 public Gato(){
    initComponents();

    MAPA= new Boton[3][3];

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
             MAPA [i][j]=new Boton();
             MAPA[i][j].u.setBounds((i*230)+10,(j*230)+10,230,230);
             MAPA[i][j].u.addActionListener(this);
             this.add(MAPA[i][j].u);
         }

     }
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     JLabel o=new JLabel("Hola");
     o.setBounds(60, 60, 100, 100);
     this.add(o);

}
```

Comment: For many components in one space (e.g. both game and menu), use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) (in the frame) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: `o.setBounds(60, 60, 100, 100);` Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How* you should structure your `JPanels` inside a `JFrame` is an an architectural question that is beyond the scope of this site.

To help wrap your head around what the difference between these two sorts of containers:

Change `public class Gato extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {`

to `public class Gato extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener {`

Then, create a new "driver" class that does something like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
         JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
          Gato gato = new Gato(); 
          frame.setContentPane(gato);
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The only difference between a JFrame and a JPanel is that a JFrame is a top-level container - it exists as its own window - while a JPanel is something that has to be loaded inside a top-level container. [Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/People/pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/view/index.html) is a great discussion about the difference between them conceptually.

In practice, once you have your frame created and your panel embedded into it (there are some quirks to this process, and I'll admit they tripped me up quite a few times when I was first wrapping my head around Swing - be sure to read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/) very carefully, paying particular attention to `JFrame.pack()` and `JPanel.validate()`), you can treat that panel exactly as you would if it was a frame.

In fact, I often test JPanel elements by changing them to JFrames in order to test them independent of any container.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding components to the `JFrame`, add them to a `JPanel`, then add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.

Comment: tried that... but it wont show the JPanel on the JFrame idk why

Comment: @AlbertoCantu Then post the code where you do this so we can see what the problem really is. Understand that when you add components to a `JFrame` it really adds them to its content pane which behaves like a `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Well for your problem you just need one JDesktopPane and All your JFrame need JIternalFrame and call all InternalFrame in JDesktopPane.

[Go to this link and check out examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JDesktopPanedemo.htm)

you don't need to convert them into panel and all.
or you can also try netbeans inbuilt examples for JDesktopPane.

Comment: Why would he need many frames? This is only confusing to the user and serves no purpose in game menus if your menu is floating in one place and the game somewhere else.